# Scrolling is not working properly in RecyclerView

Tags: android

I am working with `RecyclerView` and knows that it has good scrollilg efficiency. In my code I am using `RecyclerView` for populating data. But my scrolling is not working properly. Getting stuck while changing from one cell to another. Here is my code. Iam using `LinearLayoutManager`.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<DataList> openItems;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<DataList> openItems) {

        this.context = context;
        this.openItems = openItems;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.test_layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light));
        } else {
            holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light));
        }

        holder.workstationPk.setText(String.valueOf(openItems.get(position).getWorkstationPk()));
        holder.supplier.setText(openItems.get(position).getSupplier());
        holder.quantity.setText(openItems.get(position).getQuantity());
        holder.description.setText(openItems.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.partNo.setText(String.valueOf(openItems.get(position).getPartNo()));
        holder.forecastDate.setText(String.valueOf(openItems.get(position).getForecastDate()));
        holder.carType.setText(openItems.get(position).getCarType());
        holder.hours.setText(openItems.get(position).getHours());
        holder.custodianName.setText(openItems.get(position).getCustodianName());
        holder.function.setText(openItems.get(position).getFunction());
        holder.priority.setText(openItems.get(position).getPriority());
        holder.comment.setText(openItems.get(position).getComment());
        holder.categoryDisplayText.setText(openItems.get(position).getCategoryDisplayText());
        holder.subcategoryDisplayText.setText(openItems.get(position).getSubcategoryDisplayText());
        holder.disposition.setText(openItems.get(position).getDisposition());
        holder.reworkOrder.setText(openItems.get(position).getReworkOrder());
        holder.resourceRequirement.setText(openItems.get(position).getResourceRequirement());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return openItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private EditText workstationPk;
        private EditText supplier;
        private EditText quantity;
        private EditText description;
        private EditText partNo;
        private EditText forecastDate;
        private EditText carType;
        private EditText hours;
        private EditText custodianName;
        private EditText function;
        private EditText priority;
        private EditText categoryDisplayText;
        private EditText subcategoryDisplayText;
        private EditText comment;
        private EditText disposition;
        private EditText reworkOrder;
        private EditText resourceRequirement;

        private TextView workstationPkTextView;
        private TextView supplierTextView;
        private TextView quantityTextView;
        private TextView descriptionTextView;
        private TextView partNoTextView;
        private TextView forecastDateTextView;
        private TextView carTypeTextView;
        private TextView hoursTextView;
        private TextView custodianNameTextView;
        private TextView functionTextView;
        private TextView priorityTextView;
        private TextView categoryDisplayTextTextView;
        private TextView subcategoryDisplayTextTextView;
        private TextView commentTextView;
        private TextView dispositionTextView;
        private TextView reworkOrderTextView;
        private TextView resourceRequirementTextView;

        private LinearLayout linearLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            workstationPk = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.workstationPk);
            supplier = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.supplier);
            quantity = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            description = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            partNo = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.partNo);
            forecastDate = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.forecastDate);
            carType = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.carType);
            hours = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hours);
            custodianName = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.custodianName);
            function = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.function);
            priority = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.priority);
            categoryDisplayText = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryDisplayText);
            subcategoryDisplayText = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subcategoryDisplayText);
            comment = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
            disposition = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.disposition);
            reworkOrder = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.reworkOrder);
            resourceRequirement = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.resourceRequirement);

            workstationPkTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.workstationPkTextView);
            supplierTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.supplierTextView);
            quantityTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantityTextView);
            descriptionTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView);
            partNoTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.partNoTextView);
            forecastDateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.forecastDateTextView);
            carTypeTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.carTypeTextView);
            hoursTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hoursTextView);
            custodianNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.custodianNameTextView);
            functionTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.functionTextView);
            priorityTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.priorityTextView);
            categoryDisplayTextTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryDisplayTextTextView);
            subcategoryDisplayTextTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subcategoryDisplayTextTextView);
            commentTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentTextView);
            dispositionTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dispositionTextView);
            reworkOrderTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.reworkOrderTextView);
            resourceRequirementTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.resourceRequirementTextView);

            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Getting stuck while changing from one cell to another."? Do you mean the performance isn't good or do you mean it literally gets locked and you can't scroll?

Comment: Stuck means scrollilng is done. But not getting a smooth scrolling.